# Listener to detect map change made by the user and not by the API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to detect any change made by the user in a Google Map (zoom in, zoom out, move, etc) but not fire up when I change the map through the API like map.setZoom(zoom) or   map.panTo(centerLocation).

I have now:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function ()
{
    var search = $("#Search").val();
    var categoryId = $("#Category_Id").val();

    if (search != "" && categoryId > 0)
        companyGetAllByCategoryOnMapMoveSubmit();
});
```

But it fires up with a user zoom and a javascript map.setZoom(8), and I only want to listen to the users events.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a state variable which can identify how the listener has been invoked. Suppose the state variable is true if you have called the API otherwise false. In your listener check for that state variable and if it is  true do nothing and set the state variable to false. I mean

```
var globalState = false;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function ()
{
    if(!globalState) {
        var search = $("#Search").val();
        var categoryId = $("#Category_Id").val();

        if (search != "" && categoryId > 0)
            companyGetAllByCategoryOnMapMoveSubmit();
    }
    globalState = false;
});
```

Now whenever you call your API set the globalState to true

```
globalState = true;
map.setZoom(8) /* or any other API */
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. This was an option but I would like to know if the Api provides this option by design

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a possibility given by the API.

If you have to handle multiple events (and need to skip them on API calls) another solution might be to disable all events before the API call (thus remove them) and to re-enable them back when the API call is done.

Have a look at my example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map_canvas {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

        function initialize() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.518998, -0.148315),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                    mapOptions);

            var changeListener;

            function handleMapChange() {
                console.log("Handle map change done by user!");
            }

            function zoomOut(mouseEvent) {
                // disable all events that should not get fired
                disableUserEvents();
                // do API call
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
                // re-enable temporary disabled events when API operation finished
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", enableUserEvents);
            }

            function disableUserEvents() {
                console.log("disable User Events");
                google.maps.event.removeListener(changeListener);
                changeListener = undefined;
            }

            function enableUserEvents() {
                console.log("enable User Events");
                changeListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", handleMapChange);
            }

            // enable user triggered events
            enableUserEvents();

            // the following rightclick listener will trigger an API call (zoomOut)
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", zoomOut);

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```